# Unite adjacent ranges from different rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose there is a company with several departments. Each of them has one or a few ranges of internal phone numbers assigned to it. Assignment is stored in one database table, but in different manner for different departments, like this:

```
dept_name    range_start    range_end

Sales        10             19
Sales        20             29
HR           30             49
Finance      60             65
Finance      84             93
```

How can adjacent ranges be selected as united, so that for Sales dept. there will be just one row in results, like this:

```
dept_name    range_start    range_end

Sales        10             29
HR           30             49
Finance      60             65
Finance      84             93
```

?

Comment: Why are they different ranges in the data to begin with if they are continuous?

Comment: @MikeBrant God knows. Someone's legacy.

Comment: It's just rows in a database. why not fix it to combine those rows?

Comment: Are you wanting to check for continuous rows or just combine those rows where `dept_name = 'Sales'`?

Comment: @MikeBrant Well, I don't know how to fix them either. This post is just example, in fact the table has around 30k rows.

Comment: @sgeddes I want to combine all rows with continuous data, which belong to same departments. In other words, continuous data for same dept. should not be broken apart into several rows.

Comment: SO perhaps write a script to investigate the rows and consolidate them.  I would think that doing that on a one time basis is much more efficient than trying to run some really crazy innefficient query all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by finding all the range starts, all the range ends, and then joining them together in the right order.

Here's a SQLfiddle that demonstrates this concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cd35/24

And the query...

```
SELECT oStart.dept_name, oStart.range_start, oEnd.range_end
FROM
(
    SELECT strt.dept_name, strt.range_start, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM
      (
        SELECT d1.dept_name, d1.range_start, d1.range_end
        FROM DepartmentPhoneRanges AS d1
        LEFT JOIN DepartmentPhoneRanges AS d2
          ON d1.dept_name = d2.dept_name AND d1.range_start = d2.range_end + 1
        WHERE d2.dept_name IS NULL
      ) AS strt
      , 
      (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY dept_name, range_start
) AS oStart
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT end.dept_name, end.range_end, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank2
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT d1.dept_name, d1.range_start, d1.range_end
        FROM DepartmentPhoneRanges AS d1
        LEFT JOIN DepartmentPhoneRanges AS d2
          ON d1.dept_name = d2.dept_name AND d1.range_end = d2.range_start - 1
        WHERE d2.dept_name IS NULL
      ) AS end
      , 
      (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
    ORDER BY dept_name, range_end
) AS oEnd
ON oStart.dept_name = oEnd.dept_name AND oStart.rank = oEnd.rank2
;
```

NB - with no ROW_NUMBER() function in mySQL (As there is in SQL Server) I used the trick in `OMG Ponies`' answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) as a stand-in